# How to properly import a file in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm working on my C++ homework, and the assignment is to create a main.cpp file, which "includes" a clock.cpp file. However, when I try to import the clock.cpp file, I get an error in Xcode that "file not found." What am I doing wrong?

Here is the main.cpp code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clock.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // set the clock to 4:58:45
    Clock clock(4, 58, 45);

    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        clock.tick();
        cout << clock.get_hours() << ":" << clock.get_minutes() << ":" << clock.get_seconds() << endl;
    }
}
```

And here's a screenshot of the project:

[image]

Comment: Is your `clock.cpp`an external file that you are trying to add to your project by **drag & drop**?

Comment: Check that clock.cpp is actually in the same directory as main.cpp. The groups in xcode's project navigator do not necessarily have anything to do with the directory structure. Also, could you explain why you want to include a .cpp file?

Comment: @nayem I think so, yes. It's a separate file in my Downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding your `clock.cpp` file by dragging and dropping to your project make sure you have **checked** *copy items if needed* and *add to target*. Here is a screenshot, take a look

[image: screenshot]

[image: success screenshot]